# Cannot find stored elements in Apache JSC cache

Tags: apache, caching, configuration

I'm using a JSC cache to store big amounts of objects that my application is using (more than 10.000.000)
I wrote a quick test to check the configuration, and although the elements seem to be stored in cache, when i'm trying to retrieve them, most of them aren't there. 
I use a region cache and an auxiliary Disc Cache, as you can see from my configuration file

```
jcs.region.testCache1=DC
jcs.region.testCache1.cacheattributes=org.apache.jcs.engine.CompositeCacheAttributes
jcs.region.testCache1.cacheattributes.MaxObjects=1000
jcs.region.testCache1.cacheattributes.MemoryCacheName=org.apache.jcs.engine.memory.lru.LRUMemoryCache
jcs.region.testCache1.cacheattributes.UseMemoryShrinker=true
jcs.region.testCache1.cacheattributes.MaxMemoryIdleTimeSeconds=3600
jcs.region.testCache1.cacheattributes.ShrinkerIntervalSeconds=60
jcs.region.testCache1.cacheattributes.MaxSpoolPerRun=500
jcs.region.testCache1.elementattributes=org.apache.jcs.engine.ElementAttributes
jcs.region.testCache1.elementattributes.IsEternal=true

jcs.auxiliary.DC=org.apache.jcs.auxiliary.disk.indexed.IndexedDiskCacheFactory
jcs.auxiliary.DC.attributes=org.apache.jcs.auxiliary.disk.indexed.IndexedDiskCacheAttributes
jcs.auxiliary.DC.attributes.DiskPath=${user.dir}/jcs_swap
jcs.auxiliary.DC.attributes.MaxPurgatorySize=10000
jcs.auxiliary.DC.attributes.MaxKeySize=-1
```

I set the eternal attritbute to 'true', so that the elements are never expired and removed, an memory shrinker that puts the elements periodically to the DiscCache, and a DiscCache whose MaxKeySize is set to -1, indicating that it can host whatever amount of alements. Do u see any misconiguratiokn?

When I use this configuration with medium amount of elements (~10.000) everything works fine. When I'm using it with more than 1.000.000, I cannot retrieve most of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I found a solution by my own. I was inserting elements in the cache by executing the following snipset

```
for(Integer i=0; i<2000000; i++) {

            TestElement element = new TestElement();
            element.setId(i);
            element.setValue("element" + i);
            cache.add(i, element);            
}
```

This caused troubles, because the cache didn't have the time to spool elements in the disk cache. However if I use sleep for a couple of msecs before adding new elements (which makes more sense in a real time environment) everything works as expected